# how to request only new or changed co-ordinates from a servlet?

Tags: java, android, servlets

I have a list of co-ordinates on my server.
I want the android phone to request the list from a servlet when it first time it is ran.
Then if i put a new co-ordinates in the list , i want the phone to only download the new co-ordinates.

How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

you have to track the time of co-ordinates added. And to save last time when android client access you servlet. Next you call /yourServlet?takenewfrom=lastaccessdate
 On the server side use sql select "where timeadded>?" or sortable collection.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more than one approach to tackle the problem. For eg. For the first time when android client client download list send parameter list = freshdata and from next time just download the changed data by sending list = changeddata